# Difficulties with alternate routing

Tags: php

I am working on a PHP project for myself. My folder structure is like this:

```
index.php
head.php
config
    config.php (database connection)
src
    the other php files (ie. nav.php, stats.php)
helpers
    the "oncerunning scripts" (ie. login.php, logout.php)
css
    style.css
```

In the start of index.php and almost every php's in the src and helpers directoris I included 'head.php'. If I run the index.php, everything is OK, but If I login it causes WSOD, becouse login.php gets the head.php `(../head.php)`, but head.php don't give it the path to the config file (it forwards that the config.php is in the config/ directory, but there aren't any config directory in the helpers directory)

How I can debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try use Absolute Paths and not relative paths,
   this because relative paths are called based on the executed php script.
2. the other option is to allow one script manage all processes; e.g. file : index.php

   ```
   <?php
   include_once('config/config.php');
   ...//various configurations
   if ($state == $login)
   {
       include_once('src/login.php');
   }
   else if ($state == $stats)
   {
       include_once('src/stats.php');
   }
   ```

then you will only need to configure relative paths according to one php script, in this case script index.php

Comment: Thank you. And should I put the primary files in the same directory as the index.php?

Comment: Not Necessarily. if you are using index.php as the main point of execution the pathes can be relative to index.php. or you can have one file in each sub dir that grabs all the necessary configurations when needed, this is especially impotant for the config files and class files.